# mapping multiple strings into a number variable in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python programming in need of your expertise. I have come across a exercise whereby I am needed to map string characters into numerals. For example A,B,C=2; D,E,F=3 and so on. If I have a telephone number eg 555-get-food, what would be the code to convert the characters into numerals?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry but this is not how StackOverflow works. You must show effort in researching, posting the code you have tried, explaining why it's not working and asking an specific question.

Comment: Use a `dict` like so: `mapping={'A':2, 'B':2, 'C':2, 'D':3, 'E':3,...}` Then retrieve with `mapping['A']`

Comment: @Christian Sorry that is not how the python community works. We help each other even when we don't even know how to ask the question.

Comment: this isn't needing 'expertise', only basic coding knowledge. specifically of dictionaries

Comment: @ChristopherMahan I don't want to be rude, but that's not the way SO works. And I think this site is SO.

Comment: @Christian I understand what you're saying, but you also need to understand that good "customer service" does wonders for language adoption.

Comment: @ChristopherMahan I understand your point of view too, but if we act as if this kind of questions are good, then more and more people will make poor quality questions, which will lead into the StackOverflow destruction. This is discussed a lot in Meta.

Comment: @Christian Ok, I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. One of the most straightforward would probably be a python dictionary. The python tutorials has a couple of great examples that can be seen here:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

As a super simple example of setting up a dictionary using some of your values above

```
>>> phone={'a':2, 'd':3}
>>> print phone['a']
2
>>> print phone['d']
3
```